what is the lower pressure plate in the swashplate assembly? is it the same as the lower stationary swash plate? or is it the drive scissors?
Im looking at the rotor assembly of a BlackHawk. The natops manual states the following, "...The lower pressure plate, in conjunction with the main shaft nut, secures the shaft extension to the main shaft. The lower pressure plate also provides an attachment for the swashplate assembly. The swashplate has stationary and rotating discs separated by a bearing. It transmits flight control movement to the main rotor through four pitch control rods. The swashplate slides around the main rotor shaft and tilts in the direction of the flight controls on a Teflon-coated uniball."
What exactly is the lower pressure plate? based on the drawing it looks like its pointing to what in other books/sources its called "drive scissors" (the articulable 2-piece link attached to the main shaft to the rotating plate)? or is it the rotating upper plate the lower pressure plate? thank you in advance.
I just don't see any other plate than the fixed and rotating plate..
last, what is the main shaft nut? Is it part or under the fairing or is it part of the fairing?


"The lower pressure plate, in conjunction with the main shaft nut, secures the shaft extension to the main shaft. The lower pressure plate also provides an attachment for the swashplate assembly" what's not clear in the explanation? How the extension of the shaft works? Or how the scissors works?
